# How can one Java thread check the state of another one, e.g. whether the other one is blocked?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a question asked to one of my friends during an interview.

> How do you know whether a thread is blocked inside a synchronized method, from another thread?

Can anybody please explain this using an example?

Comment: *How do you know whether a thread is blocked inside a synchronised method form another thread?* you can know if it HAS BEEN blocked by checking `Thread.getState()` (but not the present state). It is important aspect since it doesn't guarantee anything in multi-threaded environment, i.e. the result is useful for debugging only.

Comment: Does `jconsole` / `jmx`  counts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `Thread.getState()`:

```
Thread.State state = getThreadInQuestion().getState();
if(state == Thread.State.BLOCKED) {
    System.out.println("Blocked");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not blocked");
}
```

Outside of a VM, you can use the `jstack` tool to get full thread information for every thread, or connect to JMX and explore the Thread MBeans.

Comment: +1: Of course you will never see the current thread blocked, only another thread.

Answer (score 2):

My short answer would be "no, not reliably".

Somebody mentioned checking for `getState() == Thread.State.BLOCKED`. **However, by the time you get the answer it may already be obsolete** if the blocked thread is waiting on a monitor locked by a third thread, and the monitor gets released just as `getState` is about to return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can know that. But you can do `Thread.currentThread()` which will tell you the thread which is executing the method.

Answer (score 0):

Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread.State state = t1.getState();